# Issue in accessing member variables

Tags: c++, inheritance, initialization

```
#include<iostream>

class A {
    int a, b;
public:
    void setdata(int x, int y) { a = x; b = y; }
    void showdata() { std::cout << a << b; }
};

class B : public A { };

int main() {
    A  a1;
    B  b1;
    a1.setdata(5, 4);
    a1.showdata();
    b1.showdata();
}
```

I just want to print the values of the `a` and `b` members using the `b1` object of class `B`, as it can access the member functions of class `A` since class `B` has public inheritance of class `A`. But, I am getting garbage values when I try to print the values of `a` and `b` using `b1`.

Can someone explain why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: You don't call `setdata` on the `b1` instance. And please read up on constructors.

Comment: It seems like you assume `b1` should print the values provided to `a1`, but `b1` has nothing to do with `a1`. What if you have another `A`? How would `b1` know which `A`'s value to use? I'm not sure I understand your mental model for how inheritance works.

Answer (score 3):

`a1` and `b1` are completely separate object instances in memory.  They have their own copies of the `a` and `b` members in memory.  They have nothing to do with each other at all.  Whatever you do to `a1` does not affect `b1` at all, and vice versa.

You are initializing the members of `a1` only, you are not initializing the members of `b1` at all.  That is why you are seeing garbage when you try to print out the members of `b1`.

Before calling `b1.showdata()`, you need to call `b1.setdata()` to initialize `b1`'s members, eg:

```
int main() {
    A  a1;
    B  b1;
    a1.setdata(5, 4);
    a1.showdata();
    b1.setdata(1, 2); // <-- add this!
    b1.showdata();
}
```

You should also give `class A` a default constructor that initializes the members to default values, in case `setdata()` is not called after construction (such as what happened in your case), eg:

```
class A {
    int a, b;
public:
    A() : a(0), b(0) {} // <-- add this!
    void setdata(int x, int y) { a = x; b = y; }
    void showdata() { std::cout << a << b; }
};
```

Alternatively, you might consider giving `class A` and `class B` a constructor that takes values as input, eg:

```
class A {
    int a, b;
public:
    A() : a(0), b(0) {}
    A(int x, int y) : a(x), b(y) {} // <-- add this!
    void setdata(int x, int y) { a = x; b = y; }
    void showdata() { std::cout << a << b; }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B() : A() {}
    B(int x, int y) : A(x, y) {}
};

/* or simpler:

class B : public A {
public:
    using A::A; // <-- inherit all constructors
};
*/

int main() {
    A  a1(5, 4);
    B  b1(1, 2);
    a1.showdata();
    b1.showdata();
}
```

Comment: It's ok. But my question is, as B inherits the member functions of A, I am trying to print the values of a and b  of  a1  using  b1 through showdata () as  b1  can use it. But it is not working, why?.

Comment: Read the 1st paragraph of my answer, I already addressed that question. Just because `B` derives from `A` does not mean that object `b1` can access object `a1`'s data. You clearly have a fundamental misunderstanding of how objects actually work.  You need to get yourself a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/) that covers this in detail.

Comment: What I am trying to do is to print the variables of  a1 using  b1 but not the variables of  b1 as  b1 can access the showdata() function because of inheritance.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau  If B cannot access the values of a then how was I able to set values to a and b of class A using setdata() with the help of an obj of class B that is b1 and was able to print them using showdata() usng the same b1.

Comment: @ravikiran You clearly do not understand what inheritance is or how objects work. Again, stop what you are doing and go get some [good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/) to study. `B` simply inherits the same *functionality* as `A`. What `A` can do, `B` can also do. That DOES NOT mean that `b1` has access to `a1`'s data members. `b1` has its own data members. `a1` and `b1` DO NOT share the same memory, so what you are asking for is simply not possible.